# Resume AVPlayer video when applicationDidBecomeActive?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avplayer

Currently playing a video as my background in a view using AVPlayer, but when I return to the home screen and then reopen the app, the video is paused and I can't get it to resume. Of course closing the app and reopening fixes it, but really I need it to resume when the user returns to the app. 
I've tried using applicationDidBecomeActive in the AppDelegate, by creating a variable linking to my viewcontroller then calling avPlayer.play(). However this then throws back an error saying found nil. I've also tried calling viewDidLoad() in applicationDidBecomeActive which then gives me a BAD INSTRUCTION error even though the code works perfectly when not calling it from delegate.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var avPlayer: AVPlayer!
    var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!
    var paused: Bool = false
    var foregroundNotification: NSObjectProtocol!

    //viewDidLoad

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(ViewController.viewDidLoad), name:NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object:UIApplication.shared)


        //Rotate icon

        let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
        rotateAnimation.toValue = 360.0
        rotateAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE
        rotateAnimation.duration = 450


        checkInButton.layer.add(rotateAnimation, forKey: "myAnimationKey");

        //Play background video

        let theURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"city2", withExtension: "mp4")

        avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: theURL!)
        avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
        avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        avPlayer.volume = 0
        avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = .none
        //avPlayer.rate = 1

        avPlayerLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, at: 0)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd(notification:)),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                               object: avPlayer.currentItem)

}


    func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: Notification) {
        let p: AVPlayerItem = notification.object as! AVPlayerItem
        p.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        avPlayer.play()
        paused = false

    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        avPlayer.pause()
        paused = true

}
}
```

Delegate:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var vc = ViewController()


    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

        vc.avPlayer.play()
        vc.paused = false

    }
```

Comment: Try adding the NotificationCenter with the NameWillEnterForeground in the ViewDidAppear or ViewWillAppear functions. And create a function that will initiate the avPlayer.play() in the ViewController.

Answer (score 1):

Set up notification once like this.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToForeground), name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
```

Then deal with your music playing here

```
func appMovedToForeground() {
    //do you play stuff here
}
```